# How to limit visible Navigation Topics in Community based on user profiles?

Tags: community, knowledge, topics, data-category

I’m setting up a Community for internal help desk style functionality.  I’ve got data categories working fine for article visibility.  But there seems to be a disconnect with managing Navigational topic visibility?  A user can see and drill down through all topics, even if the articles aren’t visible due to profile permissions.

Is there a way to resolve this?

Our Community is setup for multiple staff programs.  There are some specific topics that only single programs need access to, but the majority of the topics overlap.

Comment: I added some tags which seemed relevant. Feel free to remove them if any are off base.

Comment: Edited to clarify Navigational Topics in Communities vs Topics for records

Comment: Seeking an answer for the same.